# Flask Redirects Incorrectly When Hosted

Tags: python, flask, passenger, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm having a issue that has been stumping me with my current host. I have a simple login web app that redirects incorrectly whenever I confirm if a form is valid.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       #commit to database
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

What happens is that when the form is valid, the database updates and should redirect back to the login page but the page routes to /register/login instead of simply /login. The host im using is shared and uses a apache/passenger stack to serve python apps and the only log information I have says that a POST request is sent to /register followed by a GET to /register/login.

The Html I use is this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.email.label }}<br>
            {{ form.email(size=64) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password2.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password2(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you provide your html code?

Comment: try `url_for('login', _external=True)`

Comment: I added the HTML codeas requested. The _external=True suggestion doesn't route to login just back to the orignal register page =/.

Comment: Also from what I noticed the redirects only break inside the if form.validate_on_submit(): statements. So other features such as login and password recovery also produce these broken links.

Comment: check what you set in the `@app.route()` param of your login view. Almost certain it says `/register/login` instead of `/login`

Comment: The app.route for both register and login are both correct.

Comment: As an update I discovered that when url_for() is used the issue occurs but if I hard code the links it seems to be a quick workaround.